# Concept defining method and concrete class defining static method

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Continuing my studies on `concepts`, in the following example:

```
template <typename t>
concept c = requires(t p_t) {
  { p_t.f() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

template <c t_c> int m1(t_c p_c) { return p_c.f(); }

template <c t_c> int m2() { return t_c::f(); }

struct a {
  int f() { return 3; }
};

struct b {
  static int f() { return 4; }
};

int main() {
   std::cout << m1(a{}) << std::endl;
   std::cout << m2<b>() << std::endl;
}
```

Shouldn't `std::cout << m2<b>() << std::endl;` to cause a compiler error, since `b` does not satisfy `c`?

I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0`, and there was no compile or runtime error.

Comment: It is perfectly legal to call static methods on instances using `.`, so it does in fact satisfy `c`

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
``` 
template <typename t>
concept c = requires(t p_t) {
  { t::f() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
``` instead?

Comment: Yes, though the `(t p_t)` would be unnecessary for that constraint. This is what I'm trying to tell you though: https://godbolt.org/z/b8Tq9qanP

Comment: @canellas inline formatting just uses one `\`` (one backtick) `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Concepts are not *base classes*. You do not (or at least, *should not*) define concepts on the basis of a function having a specific signature. Concepts verify the validity of *expressions* (or constant expression-y things).

And if `f` is a static member function of type `b`, and you have an instance of `b` called `t`, it is 100% legal C++ syntax to invoke `b::f` via the expression `t.f()`.

Therefore, the concept is satisfied.

Also, your template function `m2` is a liar. It claims that it will use a type in accord with the concept `c`, but then it does something that isn't part of `c`.

C++20 concepts cannot tell if a function constrained by a concept is lying. All it can do is check if the expressions are available.

And if the user wants to satisfy the concept via a static member function, you *shouldn't care*. As long as it does what it's supposed to do, let the user have the freedom to fulfill the condition as they see fit.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer, but I'm not following the train of thought in the first paragraph. Why "should" concepts only be used for certain kinds of validation and not others? I would think constraining the signature of a method would be a great usage of concepts as a form of static polymorphism analogous to virtual (or "base") classes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: "*Why "should" concepts only be used for certain kinds of validation and not others?*" 1) Because it's *way* easier to specify. 2) Because it gives the user more freedom in implementing the interface. Why should you as the creator of a concept *care* if a user provides an exact signature? What does it matter if the user has a default parameter or two on their version of the function? Unless you're doing something with that function which *explicitly* requires an exact signature, there's no need to be that controlling over the user's code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Virtual functions work the way they do, with the limitations of a (nearly) exact signature, because there's no other choice for runtime execution. By the time dynamic dispatch becomes possible, we've lost all information about what function we tried to call. So the only thing you can do is use a function pointer, which requires a well-defined, (nearly) exact signature.

Answer (score -3):

```
template <typename t>
concept c = requires(t p_t) {
  { t::f() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

template <c t_c> int m1(t_c p_c) { return p_c.f(); }

template <c t_c> int m2() { return t_c::f(); }

struct a {
  int f() { return 3; }
};

struct b {
  static int f() { return 4; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << m1(a{}) << std::endl;
  std::cout << m2<b>() << std::endl;
}
```

This would be the correct `concept`, which cause the `'a' does not satisfy 'c'`

Comment: That concept does not describe the constraint for both functions, it only expresses the usage in `m2`, not in `m1`.